# Program that not working properly

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to write some program that it count until it's found space when its found space the program break to work.

I have been problem.
my code:

```
x  = raw_input("")
i = 0
corents = 0
while(x[i] != " "):
    corennts +=i
    i+=1
name = x[:corents]
print name
```

If I will input string "Hola amigas" its returns "Hola".
I'm need the program without some built-ins/or imports file function.

I need to implement it only with while/for loops.

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 2):

`corents` is spelt wrong, 5th line down.

```
x  = raw_input("")
i = 0
corents = 0
while(x[i] != " "):
    corents +=i
    i+=1
name = x[:corents]
print name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = raw_input()
name = x.split(' ', 1)[0]
print name
```

or

```
x = raw_input()
try:
    offs = x.index(' ')
    name = x[:offs]
except ValueError:
    name = x    # no space found
print name
```

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way of doing this is like this:

```
x = raw_input("")
name = x.split(" ")[0]
print name
```

The `split` method splits the string into an array, and [0] returns the first item of that array. If you for some reason need the index:

```
x = raw_input("")
i = x.index(" ")
name = x[:i]
print name
```